# How to access current store state in redux outside of react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, store, flux

I have the below code for my redux store and everything works fine as expected when wired with react. Now I am trying to access the current state of the store in an action dispatcher (outside of react) but I am getting empty values when I use this after initial dispatch ..

```
import configureStore from '../../common/store/configureStore';
const history = createHistory();
const reduxRouterMiddleware = syncHistory(history);
// Create a new Redux store instance
const store = configureStore({},reduxRouterMiddleware);
console.log("Store data ===>"+JSON.stringify(store.getState()));
```

My store:

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import DevTools from '../containers/DevTools';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import promise from 'redux-promise';


export default function configureStore(initialState, reduxRouterMiddleware) {
    const logger = createLogger();
    const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(
        thunk,promise,
        reduxRouterMiddleware
    )(createStore);

    const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
    let store;
    if (!isProduction) {
        store = createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer, initialState, compose(
            DevTools.instrument()
        ));
    }
    else if(initialState!=''){
        store = createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer, initialState, compose(
        ));
    }else{
        store = createStore(rootReducer)
    }
    if (module.hot) {
        // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
        module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
            const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers');
            store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer)
        })
    }
    return store
}
```

**Update 1:**

I made some modification to my store variable to make store as global variable and added a function to return store and that seems to work. Is this the right way?

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import DevTools from '../containers/DevTools';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import promise from 'redux-promise';

let store;
export default function configureStore(initialState, reduxRouterMiddleware) {
    const logger = createLogger();
    const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(
        thunk,promise,
        reduxRouterMiddleware
    )(createStore);
    const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

    if (!isProduction && initialState!='') {
        store = createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer, initialState, compose(
            DevTools.instrument()
        ));
    }
    else if(initialState!=''){
        store = createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer, initialState, compose(
        ));
    }
    if (module.hot) {
        // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
        module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
            const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers');
            store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer)
        })
    }
    return store
}

export function returnStore() {
    return store
}
```

I am able to access the store as below.

```
import {returnStore} from '../../common/store/configureStore';
console.log("Store data rules ===>"+JSON.stringify(returnStore().getState().rules.data));
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `redux-thunk`, you are able to get current state of store from any *action creator* like this:

```
function someAction() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    console.log(store.getState())
  }
}
```

My sugestion is to you use that instead expose store globally.

Comment: Thank you for this!! I forgot that `redux-thunk` includes the getState function as a parameter. Super helpful and saved me a tonne of time. This should be the accepted answer as OP is using `redux-thunk`

Answer (score 0):

This would be a comment but since I don't have enough reputation let me do it some kind of answer.

First of all I am a learner like you and not expert in JS, React or Redux. Just for curiosity, where exactly do you need store? Here are some places where and how I get store:

- For React ecosystem, obviously I am using Provider.
- For Redux action creators, I am using redux-thunk.
- For React Router + Redux mix, I am using react-router-redux.

Of course you can get store like you wrote. Actually, I am not quite sure but I think with redux-thunk we are using a similar concept. In the action creator function (not action creator itself) we receive dispatch and getState from store. So, somehow it returns those methods from store like you do.